# Bike left out in triple digit heat

Tags: preventative-maintenance

I've recently relocated to Arizona.  The place I am currently staying has no indoor storage for my bike, so I have to leave it outside, all day, every day, baking in this ridiculous 100+ degree weather.

Is this going to cause any long term damage to the bike, and are there any extra maintenance steps I have to do to compensate?

Comment: My bike has been outside all day everyday for the past three years in AZ.  Only heat related issue is my grip-tape adhesive doesn't seem to be effective nearly as long in this heat.  I recently did replace my saddle but I don't think it was due to the heat, just old.  I ride 10 miles/day and haven't had to do any unusual maintenance to account for the heat.  I'm more concerned about the wetness from the monsoon season coming up.  Try not to park your bike somewhere that is in direct sunlight all day.

Comment: If the bike is not going to be used for any lengh of time consider taking the wheels inside, as the tires are the most vaunerable part to heat/sunlight

Comment: Wow. 100+. That would boil water!

Comment: @andy256 In most of the world that would be true, but here in the 'Murica we use the ridiculous Fahrenheit scale.

Comment: @jimirings Well, at least the numbers are smaller than they would be if you used Rankine. It would 560+ then!

Comment: Aside from damage to paint, seat, tires, and plastic parts from the sun, the only issue would be that your bearing lube will be slightly degraded by the heat and you should probably decrease your service intervals by about a third.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that will affect your bike is not directly heat, but UV radiation from sunlight, and that does not only happens when the sun shines directly on the bike, scattered light from the sky and nearby objects will also have an effect.

UV radiation degrades polymers, plastics, rubber, and similar, sort of toasting them, making them dull, less flexible. I mention polymers because most likely that is what the bike's paint is made of, so yes, leaving the bike out in the sun all the time will cause all sort of problems to bike, from cosmetic damage to deterioration of seals, rim brake pads, hoses, cracking of derailleur pulleys, evaporation of lubricants, etc.

My recomendation is that you find a way of building a small shelter for your bike where it can sit not only in shade but in a very dark shade, covered from direct and indirect light. What Im suggesting looks a lot like a big dog house, probably made of wood and sheet metal (probably even lined with some insulating material), it doesn't have to be fancy.

Second alternative is some soft cover, like the ones used for motorcycles, but it has to be a high or medium quality one, a cheap cover may actualy do more harm than benefit. In particular, a cover should let humidity shed out, because otherwise the vapour will suround the bike, later condensating and causing corrossion in the most hidden and unlikely places.

I don't think any maintenance will compensate for all day, every day exposure to heat (and UV radiation), because radiation may reach deeper into the material than any conditioner, which almost sure is applied as a liquid or as a paste, thus acting only at surface level. It is also very difficult to thoroughly cover all the affected parts, not to mention laborious and time consuming plus that it would be necessary to perform it in a regular basis. It is more time and cost effective to find shelter for the bike.

Comment: Wax does not protect paint? What you do at the surface can and does effect penetration of sunlight. A tire is not black by chance. Tire rubber is black because black reduces penetration. The are many surface treatments that reduce UV penetration. Sunscreen is a surface treatment - not the same treatment you would put on rubber but it is an example of a surface treatment that protects from UV.

Comment: Indeed. I dont want my answer to state that treatments are not effective, but to state that too much exposure to such environment may exceed treatment's protection capacity.

Comment: The other statement is that a surface treatment does not protect seals, grease, etc.

Comment: I am pretty comfortable grease and seals are sufficiently shielded from UV radiation even if the bike is in direct sunlight.  And seals and grease are pretty resilient to plain old heat.  Just having fun with you.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I would rather have my bike out in dry heat than wet cold.

Metal parts are not impacted by the heat (in the range you would get from outside in the sun).

Sunlight will cause the paint the fade.  Wax will protect the paint.  A cleaner wax will also removes small scuffs.

Rubber parts are impacted by the sun and heat.  Sunlight even in the cold ages rubber. If out in the sun then cover rubber parts and/or treat them with a conditioner/protectant.  ArmorAll advertises that it also protects rubber.

A leather seat is aged by heat and sun.  Shade and a leather conditioner.

[How to Protect Your Tires](http://www.autoevolution.com/news/how-to-protect-your-tires-1409.html)

> You can help the tire live longer by treating it with rubber dressing
>   containing an UV-protection agent.

Agree with the comment from mattnz. I get sloppy when I put tire foam on and the brakes suffer. Off the bike is best.  On the bike I release the cables and spray on the bottom.  Disc brakes clearly are easier to avoid.

Comment: Keep dressings away from brake pads - and therefore clean rims after treating tires (or remove for tires for treatment).